# Javascript and for loops issue

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Is something wrong with my code? I was expecting my code:

```
years=new Array();
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    for (j = 1; j < 13; ++j) {
        player.push(Math.round( nestedData[i].value[j] ))
    }

    years.push(player)
}

console.log(years)
```

to print something like:

```
    [array[12],array[12],array[12],array[12]]
```

but the result that i  get is:

```
    [array[60],array[60],array[60],array[60]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new player array inside the first for loop. The problem with your code is that the values were being pushed into the same array instance.

```
var years = [];
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    var player = [];
    for (j = 1; j < 13; ++j) {
        player.push(Math.round( nestedData[i].value[j] ))
    }
    years.push(player)
}

console.log(years)
```

Comment: Personally, I'm confused why OP was expecting four arrays of 12... This is the kind of thing where you might expect to get 12, 24, 36, 48, 60 because you expect the `years.push()` to take a copy of the array (of course, it doesn't). Anyway, +1

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol . Right , unless the OP thought that the nested loop will create a new instance of an array.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the correct answer already, please use `var` to declare your variables:

```
for (var i=0; i < 5; ++i) {
    var player = [];
    for (var j = 1; j < 13; ++j) {
        ...
```

Otherwise, it will use `i` as a global variable, which could end poorly if you have two functions looping at the same time, e.g.:

```
function loopone() {
   //wouldn't expect this to be an infinite loop eh?
   for (i=0; i < 100; i++) {
       looptwo();
   }
}
function looptwo() {
   for (i=0; i < 10; i++) {
   }
}
```